# Access StructBlock in a StreamField of a Page.get_children in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I try to render a StreamField of a child page in a Page. I don't manage to render the different StructField within the StreamField. Here is my code

```
class DefinitionPage(Page):

body = StreamField([
    ('definition', blocks.StructBlock([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(label='Titre')),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock(label='Paragraphe')),
    ]))
])

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
]
```

my template. (DefinitionPage is a child of this page.)

```
{% for post in page.get_children %}
    <h2><a href="{% pageurl post %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
    {% for block in post.body %}
        {% include_block block %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

post.title is ok but it's like there is no block in post.body.
I tried so many things and {% include_block block %} is certainly wrong. I also tried to add a custom template for the StructBlock without success.

How can I do ? I am using Django 2.0 and wagtail 2.0 (I'm new to wagtail but I read the doc)
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `page.get_children.specific` - `get_children` only returns the basic `Page` information common to all page types, which doesn't include the `body` field in `DefinitionPage`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about .specific. So I changed {% for post in page.get_children %} to {% for post in page.get_children.specific %} but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I tried to modify the context too 
`def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        definitions = self.get_children().specific()
        context['definitions'] = definitions
        return context`
and try `{% for definition in definitions %}{% for block in definition %}` but the problem seems to be the `{% include_blocks block %}`. What do you think ?

Comment: Ok somehow I deleted all my DefinitionPage so there was nothing to show...now it works with the `{% for post in page.get_children.specific %}`
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I changed my code
In the parent PageModel I added:

```
def get_context(self, request):
    context = super().get_context(request)
    definitions = self.get_children().specific()
    context['definitions'] = definitions
    return context
```

And now in my template:

```
{% for definition in definitions %}
    {% for block in definition.body %}
        {%  include_block block %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I also created a custom template for my definition (simple it's just en test):

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

<div class="definition">
    <h2>{{ value.bound_blocks.heading }}</h2>
    {{ value.bound_blocks.paragraph }}
</div>
```

Thanks a lot

Just last questions: Is there a better practice ? .specific in template or in a custom get_context() ? Is it a good practice to add custom template to StructBlock ?