# Simple wagtail streamfield template not working

Tags: django, wagtail

Its my template code:

```
{% for post in page.get_children %}
    ONE {{ post.title }} <--- it shows correct, excepted title
    {% for block in post.body %}
      TWO <--- this is NEVER showen
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Its my BlogIndexPage:

```
class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

Its my BlogPage:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)

    body = StreamField([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(classname="full title")),
        ('paragraph', blocks.RichTextBlock()),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('tags'),
            FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        ], heading="Blog information"),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]
```

I just cannot access to the block propeties, because post.body fells like empty array (I added BlogPage as child of BlogIndexPage, and I filled StreamField with some text, headings and pictures - it isn't empty)

I am sure i am missing somehting obvious but I cannot see it myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access StructBlock in a StreamField of a Page.get\_children in Wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973531/access-structblock-in-a-streamfield-of-a-page-get-children-in-wagtail)